# Is the convergence of integrals a sufficient and necessary condition for uniform convergence?

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n \to f$ uniformly in $[a,b]$. If each $f_n$ is integrable in $[a,b]$,then $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b f_n(x) dx \to \int_a^b f(x) dx$.

If $\int_a^b f_n(x) dx \nrightarrow  \int_a^b f(x) dx$,then the convergence is not uniform.

But, if  $\int_a^b f_n(x) dx \to \int_a^b f(x) dx$, can we conclude then that the converge is uniform? Is it a sufficient and necessary condition?

Comment: No. Take $f(x)=\sqrt n$ if $x\in[0,1/n]$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @DavidMitra But,if a function is Riemann integrable,isn't the interval at which it is integrable bounded?

Comment: In the last comment, I took $[a,b]=[0,1]$. You can find examples where the $f_n$ are uniformly bounded too.